# $user->groups is null after editing user and saving

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Something odd is happening after a user edits his account and saves it. Once the user saves, the group array inside the user object is null.

We have it set up so that the user can be in multiple groups such as Registered and Manager (ids 2 and 15). So when a user is logged in, we can do the following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
var_dump($user->groups);
```

and we get

```
array (size=3)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  13 => string '13' (length=2)
  25 => string '25' (length=2)
```

Then after a user edits his account, changes something (or doesn't change anything), and saves,

```
var_dump($user->groups);
```

results in

```
null
```

I have tried to work around this by creating a plugin where after user is saved, we go into the database, get the user's groups, and insert them back into the array. But when I do the following:

```
public function onUserAfterSave($juser, $isNew, $result, $error)
{
    if (JFactory::getApplication()->isSite()) {

        $user = JFactory::getUser();

        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(json_encode($user->groups), 'message');
    }
}
```

the message that shows up is a JSON encoded array of the groups - *not* "null", as I was expecting. So inside onUserAfterSave(), $user->groups is still correct. It is at some point *after* this that $user->groups decides to empty itself.

Also might be important to note that every time a user logs out and logs back in, the groups are reset and it is no longer null.

Does anyone else have this problem or have any tips?

Comment: I have same problem. Have you get a chance to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had the Same Problem. Found a dirty Solution to Work around.
You can get the groups with the JACCESS Class.

```
$oUser   = JFactory::getUser();
jimport( 'joomla.access.access' );
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($oUser->id);
var_dump($groups);
```